# como puedo crear un array dinamico bidimensional(no matriz) en c++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

se pide ingresar en un arreglo nombres pero sin conocer limites de la cantidad de datos ni nombres de datos he intentado hacer lo siguiente.(el uso de strings esta prohibido)

mi idea es crear un ciclo que cuente cuantas veces se va digitar y de ahi crear el arreglo dinamico con la cantidad de palabras y luego guardar en el espacio del arreglo la palabra.

```
char categoria;
unsigned short int i;
unsigned short int k;
short int tam;

while(categoria){
    cout<<"ingrese la categoria: ";
    cin>>categoria;
    tam=sizeof(categoria);
    i++;
}
cout<<endl;

double char **arreglo = new double char[i][10];
```

Comment: ¿Por qué "*el uso de strings está prohibido*"?

Answer (score 0):

Como lo estás haciendo no compilará. Tienes un puntero a un puntero, por lo que debes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
int** arreglo = new int*[columnas];
for (int i = 0; i < columnas; i++)
    arreglo[i] = new int[filas];
```

---

A partir de C++11 puedes reservar memoria de esta manera:

```
int columnas = 5;
auto matriz = new int[columnas][3];
// Necesariamente el segundo valor debe ser una constante.
```

Las ventajas sobre el método anterior, son que usas un nivel menos de indirección y los datos no están dispersos en la memoria. Las filas ocupan bloques de memoria adyacentes.

Puedes comprobarlo [imprimiendo las posiciones de memoria de cada columna](https://tio.run/##lVA9b8IwEN3zK57ShYKRWigdklCp/6B7wmCZgCwlZ@TY6hD5t6d2cFKq0qG3WH539z5OXC7rsxDD8CBJNPZYo5CqM7rm7VuSSDJouaTFY5/Al1DUGQT0JBveYY9tPjYCJFRjWxrRTZ5M8HIJrnV9bpTHqf4csXKaPVzXO3PMMqGsQVEg/bBkaq3Ap80MaWhMPGGmovS6elIaiyAvPf9T7p9iduJ/q1W0HioSlPLw7aUck0Qfv7zcbARVhqjq7tiuqKL32XC8ALdGBZYbwTl7lEaP/plhw7B1DP0Lw47h1cHduU1g@mf8P4P9COWG4Qs). Verás que si la constante es 3, hay exactamente 3*4 bytes de diferencia entre cada una (porque cada int ocupa 4 bytes).

La clara desventaja es que la segunda dimensión debe ser constante.

---

Una tercera opción que te funcionará con cualquier versión de C++ consiste en reservar una porción de memoria lo suficientemente grande para contener todos los elementos.

La desventaja es que tendrás que "indizar" las posiciones de los elementos tu mismo pero no es el fin del mundo.

Por ejemplo:

```
int* tabla = new int[columnas * filas];
// Para llegar al elemento en la columna a y la fila b
tabla[a * filas + b] = 21;
```

Puedes ver esta [pregunta relacionada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/936702/13419694).

Answer (score 0):

Para crear un arreglo bidimensional primero creas las filas:

```
char **arreglo = new char*[filas];
```

Y después las rellenas:

```
for (int fila = 0; fila != filas; ++fila)
    arreglo[fila] = new char[columnas];
```

Mejor aún, no uses `new`, usa contenedores estándar:

```
using palabra = std::array<char, 10>;
using coleccion = std::vector<palabra>;
```

Cada vez que necesites añadir un elemento es tan sencillo como:

```
coleccion c;

palabra p = {"Test"};
c.push_back(p);
```